# HTML with HTTP request: always returns 0

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, httprequest, microsoft-edge

I am new to HTML with JavaScript:

My code is:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false);

function processRequest(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
    }
    else{
        alert(xhr.status);
    }
}
xhr.open('GET', "http://localhost:8080/hello", true);
xhr.send();
```

I always get `xhr.status` as 0? I an testing with Chrome and Edge. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking at `xhr.status` before the request is complete. Only check `status` when `readyState` is `4`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false);
function processRequest(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
            // All good
            console.log(xhr.status);
        }
        else {
            // Something went wrong
            alert(xhr.status);
        }
    }
}
xhr.open('GET', "http://localhost:8080/hello", true);
xhr.send();
```

That said, on all major browsers, `XMLHttpRequest` is obsolete. Instead, use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch):

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080/hello")
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(response.status);
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        // Read the body of the response
        return response.text(); // or .json(), .arrayBuffer(), .blob(), .formData()
    })
    .then(data => {
        // All good, use the data
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // Handle the error
    });
```

If you prefer, instead of using the `.text`, `.json`, etc. helpers, you can use `response.body`, which is a [`ReadableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream).

---

You've said you're still getting a status of `0` with the updated code. The only way I can see that happening is if you're making a cross-origin request and being prevented by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You should be getting a fairly clear error in the web console. If that's the case, look into [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) (if you control the other end) or JSONP or using a server to make the request for you. There's a ***lot*** of information about the SOP and CORS out there.

Comment: @ManigandanSeetharaman - If you look in the web console (that's always the first thing to do), you'll probably see you're getting an error related to the Same Origin Policy -- I've added a note about that at the end of the above.